# How to implement the "sign in with Facebook" and "sign in with twitter" buttons?

Tags: android, facebook, button, twitter

I have downloaded several images from the web but they are all too small and therefore the resolution gets bad on scale up. What is the proper way of getting these specific buttons to my application? (Just the interface-I have already implemented the back end )

Comment: Not really a programming question, unlikely to get a decent answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find 3rd party created icons online [here is one place to find such icons](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=twitter). Make sure when you find one to use you check out the license that it is released under and follow it. Some require to you to give attribution in certain ways, others are not available for commercial use. etc.. Top left corner when you click on an icon you'll find link to the license terms.

Comment: This site does not have the specific ones. "Sign in with twitter" nor "login with facebook"

Comment: start with a logo and make your own?

Comment: that is one solution but I was wondering what is the easiest one

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/

For Twitter : https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: i've already checked this... twitter gives us 165x28 png image which is too small on the screen. facebook's one is small as well

Comment: I did! :) I lose resolution on scale up and is not so smooth as in other apps such as foursquare for example